# Задать отступ между Button

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как задать отступ, чтобы на небольшом экране, если Button_2 налезает на Button_1, то Button_1 приподниалось вверх и между кнопками было расстояние в 3dp?

Вот разметка, Button_1 размер задается сверху, Button_2 должна быть по центру экрана по вертикали, подправьте пожалуйста:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_panel_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_1"
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#d9c1858f"
        android:text="1"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="139dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#b985c18e"
        android:text="2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 5):

То что вы показываете это изменение ориентации устройства. Для выполнения этой задачи вам нужно создать отдельный xml файл с разметкой у которого при создании будет указано что он имеет другую ориентацию.Для этого вам нужно создать новую разметку в папке `layout`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
будет выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и там уже вы можете указать нужное вам расстояние между кнопками. Для того чтобы в визуальном редакторе вы могли увидеть результаты изменений вы можете нажать на эту кнопку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же вы не хотите чтобы ваше приложение поддерживало изменение ориентации, то вам нужно в манифесте указать такую строку:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

[Вот](https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/android-portrait-landscape-screens) есть хорошая статья по вашему вопросу.

А по поводу вашей разметки которая приведена в вопросе, то вам нужно у кнопки_2 убрать тег выравнивания по правому краю и оставить центрирование в родителе:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_panel_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_1"
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#d9c1858f"
        android:text="1"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="139dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#b985c18e"
        android:text="2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

кнопка должно переместиться по центру экрана. Для того чтобы кнопки не налезали друг на друга, вам нужно указать что кнопка_2 всегда находится под кнопкой_1 таким тегом:

```
android:layout_below = "@+id/Button_1"
```

должно помочь.

### UPDATE

Как изменить марджин программно. Делаем функцию:

```
public static void setMargins (View v, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    if (v.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        p.setMargins(l, t, r, b);
        v.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

меняем марджин:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)tv.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

как получить размер экрана программно:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Если вы не в активности, тогда такой способ:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

и дальше уже делаете проверку которая вам нужна, то есть получаете размер экрана, и если он меньше или равен тому что нужно (маленькому какому-то) то вы меняете марджин.

Comment: Не помогает.. Ориентация тут не причем, так как на маленьких экранах налезает, на больших нет.. Вот же исходное условие:  У Button_1 - layout_marginTop="69dp", Button_2 распологается по центру экрана по вертикали, как на рис.1. И в случае, если эти кнопки налезут друг на друга(не важно, какая ориентация, может просто дисплей маленький), то Button_1 должна как бы изменить параметр layout_marginTop и приподняться над Button_2 на 3dp.. Я не знаю как сделать разметку с такими вроде бы не сложными условиями..

Comment: тогда вам нужно изменять параметры марджина программно при условии что экран у вас маленький, либо перейти на constraint_layout и там будут привязки

Comment: Я пытался с constraint_layout, привязал Button_1 к Button_2, но не получалось задать layout_marginTop="69dp" у Button_1,  Button_1 располагалась по центру между Button_2 и верхней границей экрана.. Эх, примерчик бы где посмотреть..

Comment: вот есть статья хорошая - https://habr.com/ru/company/touchinstinct/blog/326814/, и здесь на ruSO есть пара вопросов стоящих, если найду то добавлю в вопрос

Comment: Попробовал программно, при смене ориентации не успевает вычислить новые layout_marginTop, отсюда не получается рассчитать, налезает одна кнопка на другую или нет..

Comment: тогда считывайте данные из системы, в том плане что только при изменении ориентации меняйте марджины и все

Answer (score 4):

Когда вы делаете дизайн приложения, вы должны учитывать, что количество пикселей на устройстве как в высоту так и в ширину бывают разные. Поэтому средствами студии смотрите как выглядит разметка на разных экранах, но и этого бывает не достаточно, т.к. в настройках системы можно выставить масштабирование/размер шрифта - и вся разметка может поехать.

Не используйте размер кнопок фиксированной длинны или высоты, если они могут наложиться или не поместиться на экран.

Вашу разметку лучше перенести в `ConstraintLayout`, добавить `Guideline`, и сделать привязки кнопок не к краям экрана, а к `Guideline`:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="139dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:background="#b985c18e"
        android:text="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_1"
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:background="#d9c1858f"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Button_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Landscape][image: Portrait]
`app:layout_constraintGuide_percent` относительный отступ в процентах, указывается в значениях от 0 до 1 (0.5 - для 50%)

Ссылки на примеры базовых работ с `ConstraintLayout`:
[ConstraintLayout. Основы](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/489-urok-180-constraintlayout-osnovy.html)
[Работа с ConstraintLayout через XML-разметку](https://habr.com/ru/company/touchinstinct/blog/326814/)

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас опять пробую с ConstraintLayout, но вот исходящие условия: Button_1 - layout_marginTop="69dp", Button_2 располагается по центру экрана по вертикали, как на рис.1. В вашем примере Button_1 изначально не так располагается.. И в случае налезания кнопок друг на друга, Button_1 должна приподниматься вверх на 3dp выше Button_2.

Comment: @Alex455, вы никогда не добьетесь четких отступов, т.к. размеры ваших кнопок уже сильно ограничивают экран. Делайте все размеры относительными. сейчас исправлю код согласно вопросу.

Comment: Вот объясню немного по другому условия: Button_2 должна быть всегда по центру экрана по вертикали(рис1). Button_1 должна быть Top="69dp" если не налезает на Button_2, а если налезает, то приподниматься выше Button_2 на 3dp. Вот хотелось бы в разметке xml это сделать если возможно, чтобы не высчитывать программно все это в коде, размеры экранов и тд..

Comment: @Alex455, я вас прекрасно понял, изучите материалы. Вам не нужно всегда делать четкие размеры отступов с гибкой разметкой, достаточно правильно разместить элемент к которому дальше будут привязываться остальные. Если расположение кнопки следующего объекта зависит от размера экрана, то в этом случае лучше указывать расстояние относительное, т.е. в процентах от доступного пространства. Если хотите задать четкие размеры - тогда вам нужно делать для каждого вида экрана свою разметку, но поддерживать подобные разметки очень сложно.

Comment: @Alex455, если вам этого недостаточно, то в дополнение можете воспользоваться ответом Андрея - ресурсы можно делить не только по ориентации, но и по размерам экрана (на скрине выбрано "UI Mode", а чуть выше есть "Size" и "Screen Height"). Только плодить лучше не макеты, а размеры отступов - вынести их в `dimen`-ресурсы и наделать сколь душе угодно альтернативных размеров этим ресурсам.

Comment: Я пока не нашел решения.. Делать размеры экрана тоже не очень, все зависит от dpi, да и не знаю я всех размеров устройств.. Пока что вижу единственный выход, на подобии как предложил Andrew Goroshko, это высчитывать нижнюю и верхнюю границу кнопок, и если разница меньше к примеру 6px, то на столько же уменьшать setMargins Button_1 программно.. И делать это во всех событиях где они вызываются, при загрузке программы и при отслеживании поворота экрана.. В общем геморно как-то пока..