# Увеличение высоты кнопки при нажатии на нее?

Tags: android, android-button

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть 6 кнопок. При нажатии на любую из них, мне нужно чтобы высота увеличивалась этой кнопки. Как это сделать? Button.setHeight(); сделал. Но не работает при нажатии. Еще я пробовал увеличить высоту формы в drawable.Но все равно не получалось. В xml высота и ширина кнопки по 45dp. Я поставил на wrap_content, подумал что наверное нельзя зафиксировать размер, но все равно не выходит. Скажите пожалуйста как это сделать? Заранее спасибо

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams linnear_lay = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(45, 65);
                     linnear_lay.topMargin = 150;

                     btnWeekDay1.setLayoutParams(linnear_lay);
```

Comment: работает setHeight и setMinimumHeight , опубликуйте разметку полностью, возможно вы просто путаете View

Comment: btnWeek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnWeek.setHeight(65);
            }
        }); - Вот. Этот когда не работает

Comment: View v в параметре используйте. и дополняйте вопрос тут не нужно код писать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать таким образом:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();

            int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 35, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 140, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                layoutParams.width = width + 5;
                layoutParams.height = height + 5;
                button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                layoutParams.width = width;
                layoutParams.height = height;
                button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Вот есть подобные вопросы [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011295/change-view-height-on-click) и [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440831/how-to-make-a-button-bigger-when-pressed-android-studios).

Comment: Смотри. Я добавил картинку в вопрос. Там когда я увеличиваю высоту, высота увеличивается сверху и снизу. А мне нужно чтобы оно увеличивалось только снизу, как на первой картинке. Как это сделать?

Comment: вероятнее всего придется менять отступы программно чтобы кнопка так же и опускалась при нажатии

Comment: Я хотел это сделать. Но не нашел решение. Я хотел поменять позицию, сместить чуть-чуть вниз. Вы знаете как это сделать? Я к вопросу добавил код, который я испльзовал для изменения позиции. Но оно не сработало

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1018056/Задать-отступ-между-button/1018058#1018058

Comment: не получилось :( Я к вопросу добавил код, который я использовал для изменения позиции. Но оно не сработало. Можешь написать для одной кнопки эту функцию по изменению позиции при нажатии?

Comment: вы меняете только один марджин, а при работе с этим в программе нужно устанавливать все 4, если какой-то марджин не нужен то ставите вместо него 0, вы ознакомились с тем ответом который я дал выше?

Comment: Конечно, я так тоже сделал. Получилось. Спасибо)